# what is Example.create in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate. i have read some where about Example.create. what is it and when to use in hibernate? Please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described in the documentation. [Read it](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-examples). It allows searching by example: search for all the entities which look like this one (have the same properties).

Comment: Hi Nizet, thanks for ur reply. i went through the example. it has some example. does the example returns all Cats that matches Black color? is it similar to like search? Please help me.

Comment: Yes, the first example searches for all the cats with color BLACK and with sex "F". The second excludes the property "color", and ignores the case, so it searches for cats with sex "F" or "f".

Comment: @Nizet, Thanks for ur reply.is it similar to where condition? or is it similar to adding Restrictions in hibernate? if so, is it replacement of Restrictions? Please help me?

Comment: Given that the section of the documentation I linked to is inside the chapter "Criteria queries", and that its first sentence says: "The class org.hibernate.criterion.Example allows you to construct a query criterion", and that the first example has session.createCriteria(Cat.class).add( Example.create(cat) ), what do you deduce? Learn to read documentation and javadoc.